# initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemPageCurl not working

Tags: iphone, ios, uibarbuttonitem, page-curl

I am creating a barbutton item and adding it to my navigation controller toolbar

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemPageCurl target:self action:@selector(pageCurlAction:)] autorelease];
```

And the barbutton item is rightly loading with the toolbar in my viewcontroller.Now, I push a new viewcontroller into my view and when I pop the viewcontroller, my barbutton item with the page curl shrinks and and the page curl image is missing on the barbutton.

I tried changing the

```
initWithBarButtonSystemItem
```

with

```
UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay, UIBarButtonSystemItemPause, UIBarButtonSystemItemFastForward
```

etc. But, it works fine with them. Its just the page curl icon thats not being loaded. Any reasons for this?

Answer (score 1):

From the [*iOS Human Interface Guidelines*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW33):

> In addition, you can use the system-provided page curl button in a toolbar (for more information, see the documentation for `UIBarButtonSystemItemPageCurl` in `UIBarButtonItem` Class Reference). **The page curl button is not available for use in a navigation bar.**

(Emphasis added.)

Comment: **The system page curl button. 
This bar button image can be used only for bar button items placed on toolbars.** 
I am adding the page curl barbuttonitem to navigation controller's toolbar. Isn't that allowed?

Comment: I didn't notice that in your question.  If you're putting it in the bar at the bottom of the screen, I guess that should work.

Comment: Its working when the page loads for the first time. But, when I push a new VC and pops it out, the button shrinks and the page curl image is missing. The other images seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you use a UIToolbar, this problem can appear. It turns out the order in which you do styling and adding of toolbar items matters.

In my case I had to change from:

```
[self.toolbar setItems:items];
self.toolbar.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
```

to:

```
self.toolbar.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[self.toolbar setItems:items];
```

in order for UIBarButtonSystemItemPageCurl to start working on iOS 4.3